# How to export PATH for sublime build tool?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I wanted to create a new "build tool" for sublime text, so that I can run my python scripts with an anaconda env with tensorflow. On my other machines this works without a problem, but on my ubuntu machine with GPU support I get an error. 
I think this is due to the missing paths. The path provided in the error message doesn't contain the cuda paths, although I've included them in .bashrc.

### Update

I changed ~/.profile to export the paths. But tensorflow still won't start from sublime. Running my script directly from terminal is no problem.
I get `ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So somehow the GPU stuff (cuda?) can not be found

Thanks

Comment: I recently wrote a build tool for java and the env vars I had in `/etc/environment` have worked ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it:
The problem is that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable was missing. I only exported it in `.bashrc`.

When I add

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`

to `~/.profile` it's working (don't forget to restart). 
It also works if I start sublime from terminal with `subl` which passes all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem. From one day to another Sublime Text stopped reading some environment variables, but changing them from `.bashrc` to `.profile` didn't make a difference (specially because .profile calls .bashrc).

So one way not to start Sublime Text from terminal every time, you can add the environment variables directly to the build tool with the `env` key, like so:

```
{
  "cmd": ["python3.5", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python",
  "env":
  {
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib/folder",
    "ANOTHER_EV": "/this/other/path/if/needed"
  }
}
```

Even if for some reason sublime text starts from terminal, there shouldn't be a problem because it calls previous path.